# Redirecting to a new URL in spring 3.1 MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am very confused using spring web MVC to "redirect".

I want to redirect to a URL, but the address bar in brwser is not updated.

First, I post a form to a controller and in this controller I use the "redirect:" prefix to a new controller (it works), but the address bar is still referencing the previous URL.

Here is my code for teh controller to receive the post request:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processSubmit(LoginFormBean formBean, BindingResult result, 
    Model model) {
        System.out.println(formBean.getUsername());
    System.out.println(formBean.getPassword());
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/index");
}
```

For the controller to redirect:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/index")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Before the form is posted,  the form, URL is "http://localhost:7001/mobi"
after post and redirect, the URL is not "http://localhost:7001/mobi/index", but still "http://localhost:7001/mobi"

Are there any visible error in my code that need to be corrected?
Can the community assist me in implementing this correctly?

Comment: Aren't those two links you mention essentially the same? As a test, try redirecting to /sthElse. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

The only visible answer I can surmise based on your code is that its doubtful you have a modelandview that's a redirect to index.  You can pretty much ditch the modelandview syntax with Spring 3, and just return the pages you want directly.  Here's an example from my own code, where I also receive a posted form and redirect to another controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = REQUEST_MAP, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processForm(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, @ModelAttribute("myForm") myForm form, BindingResult result)
        throws Exception {
    //super cool form handling logic here!
    return "redirect:/anotherControllerMappedURI"; 
}
```

I could have also just returned a string to return a view page directly. Like, return "index" to send the user to an index.jsp page.  Then you could use a meta tag to do an html redirect if necessary.